# Find header value for first occurance of "1" instance in column

Tags: matrix

I have a matrix example:

```
    1   3   5   8   10  12
50  1   1   1   1   1   1
100 0   0   1   1   1   1
150 0   0   1   1   1   1
200 0   0   0   1   1   1
250 0   0   0   0   1   1
300 0   0   0   0   1   1
350 0   0   0   0   0   1
```

For each row name (50, 100, 150, 200, etc.) I want to know what is the "header" value when the instance "1" first occurs. Based on the example the answer is:

```
50 1
100 5
150 5
200 8
250 10
300 10
350 12
```

I am not sure how to play with IFs and WHENs to get my answer from this format. R, Excel, bash, awk, all welcome as solutions.

Comment: what should be printed if there is no `1` in the row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using **awk** as following :

```
$ awk 'FNR==1{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){a[i]=$i}; next} {for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){if($i=="1"){print $1, a[i-1]; break}}} ' file
50 1
100 5
150 5
200 8
250 10
300 10
350 12
```

**Explanation :**

For header i.e `FNR==1` we are populating all values in the array `a`;
For all next lines we are checking which field equates to `1`, if found print the col1 value i.e `$1` and the corresponding value in the array `a` and `break` the loop.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution:

```
awk 'NR==1{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) h[i]=$i; next }
     { 
         for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) { if($i==1) { n=h[i-1]; break } } 
         print $1,(n)?n:"None"; n=""
     }' file
```